# How To Solve "Expected type object but found type string" in REST API calls? (reactjs, javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm trying to use following Auth0 API call: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id

```
const sUserMetadata = async () => {
                const domain = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

                try {
                    const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({
                        audience: `${domain}/api/v2/`,
                        scope: "update:current_user_metadata",
                    });


                    const userDetailsByIdUrl = `${domain}/api/v2/users/${user.sub}`;
                    const metadataResponse = await fetch(userDetailsByIdUrl, {
                        method: 'PATCH',
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                        },
                        body: { "email_verified": true }
                    })

                    let user_metadata = await metadataResponse;
                    console.log(user_metadata)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            };

            sUserMetadata().then(r => null);
```

I am receiving following response error:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Payload validation error: 'Expected type object but found type string'.","errorCode":"invalid_body"}
```

Obviously the Body-Tag provides it in the correct form with Bracets {} so it Should! be an Object.

I have tried:

- JSON.parse()
- I have tried to add Content-Type which results in a freaking "SYNTAX ERROR" because of the `-` in `content-type` which doesnt make any sense because under chrome debugger I can obviously see that there is a property called `content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8` and I have no idea how else I am supposed to change this?

  ```
  headers: {
               Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
               Content-Type: 'application/json',
           },
  ```

Comment: Do you mean you've tried JSON.stringify()?

Comment: @ITgoldman i have tried both (out of desperation) but I JSON.parse() gives me an javascript object and the error says it expected an object so i only included JSON.parse() in the things i have tried section

Comment: Did you consider the fine print in the documentation? For example "Updating email_verified is not supported for enterprise and passwordless sms connections." Just guessing here.

Comment: @ITgoldman no but i tried all body examples (not only this email_verifiedn thing) so, it is as if I considered it. Im pretty sure it is fixed if i were able to change Content-Type somehow, since it is assuming its String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `Content-Type` inside Apostrophes `'Content-Type'` so it doesn't give a Syntax Error and then you using JSON.Stringify() at the Body-Tag part fixes the problem.

```
const metadataResponse = await fetch(userDetailsByIdUrl, {
                        method: 'PATCH',

                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({ "user_metadata" : { "addresses": {"work_address": "100 Industrial Way"} }}),
                    })
```

PS: save me from javascript pls